# iPhone 4S Auto-Correct

Tags: iphone, sms, spellcheck, autocorrect

Is there any way that I can get auto-correct on my iPhone 4S to stop changing the word "**Yo**" to "**To**?" I have tried adding a keyboard shortcut for "Yo" as well as adding Spanish to my International Keyboards, but its still happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Apple hasn't relegated any control of auto-correct functions to the user (natively), and it isn't possible to add or remove words that it auto-corrects - other then using the shortcuts like you mentioned, which don't work for everything.

Comment: Well, that's just annoying. 

*...Angrily shakes a fist...*